# How to pass for a third List just the common Objects?

Tags: java, list

I need to pass to the third list just the common Users between two lists.

```
List<User> listByCity = new ArrayList<User>();
List<User> listByService = new ArrayList<User>();
//initializing listByCity and listByService happens here
.
.
.
List<User> newList = new ArrayList<User>();

newList.addAll(listByCity);
newList.addAll(listByService);
```

So I have a list of Users by some city and another list of users who make some service, I need just the common users, how may I do that? I just added both lists using 'addAll' but it will not work the way I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `retainAll()` to keep the intersection of the two:

```
List<User> newList = new ArrayList<User>();
newList.addAll(listByCity);
newList.retainAll(listByService);
```

This only works if `User` implements `equals()` correctly (or if the objects are actually the same reference).

Comment: No, I haven't. I just brought the users using sql and I've added both lists on 'newList'. The way you suggested won't work 'cause of this?

Comment: @YgorFraga If you want to be able to compare users based on their properties (e.g., id, name), you need to override `equals()`. Otherwise, reference equality is used.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add equal method you can add to your User class

Answer (score 4):

Use `retainAll`

```
 List<User> newList = new ArrayList<User>(listByCity);
 newList.retainAll(listByService);
```

See example [here](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/arraylist/arraylist_retainall.php)

Since you need to override `equals` method to use retainAll, you should be able to add something like this in your `User` class

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (this == obj) {
  return true;
}
if (obj == null ||  obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
  return false;
}

User otherObj = (User) obj;

return Objects.equal(this.name, otherObj.name);
//compare all attributes of User here similar to how name is compared
}
```

Comment: You don't have to override `equals` to use `retainAll` if you want to use object identity as the equality test.

Answer (score 2):

For small lists, I'd recommend using `List.retainAll()` as the other answer suggest.

If the lists are large, you might get much better performance by creating a `HashSet` from the list that was going to be retained and explicitly iterating:

```
List<User> newList = new ArrayList<User>();
Set<User> testSet = new HashSet<>(listByService);
for (User user: listByCity) {
    if (testSet.contains(user)) {
        newList.add(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made some slight changes and the code worked as expected

Comment: @YgorFraga - Good to hear. What changes did you have to make?

Comment: Using 'HashSet' that way didn't work for me, that's weird. I used a normal list of User.

Comment: @YgorFraga - That's kind of shocking, actually. In what way did it not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream API by combining both lists and filtering them into third one:

```
    List<User> listByCity = Arrays.asList( new User("c1", "s1"), new User("c2", "s2"), new User("c1", "s3") );
    List<User> listByService  = Arrays.asList( new User("c2", "s3"), new User("c1", "s2"), new User("c1", "s3") );

    List<User> newList = Stream.concat( listByCity.stream(), listByService.stream() )
    .sequential()
    .filter( u -> u.getCity().equals("c1") && u.getService().equals("s3") )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```